# How to evaluate object detection in Python?

Tags: python, object-detection, evaluation

I have a list of ground truth and a list of corresponding prediction for object detection for a given picture in the following form:

```
ground_truth = [[0,6,234,45,362],
                [1,1,156,103,336],
                [1,36,111,198,416],
                [1,91,42,338,500]]

prediction = [[0,6,234,39,128],
              [0,3,244,39,128]
              [1,1,156,102,180],
              [1,36,111,162,305]]
```

where the individual objects are descripted as (sub)lists of `class, min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y` values for the bounding boxes for each recognized objects.

Now, I would like to have an evaluation of the correctness of the predictions against the ground truth. I know about intersection over union and F1 computed from it, but only for one class and one object. I wonder how to generalize this over multiple possible objects of multiple possible classes?

Should I iterate over each ground truth objects and iterate over all prediction objects and see which prediction is the closest? But what if a prediction partly overlaps two ground truth objects? It's confusing...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about programming or debugging. It’s a question about designing an evaluation of statistical models, which is off-topic. (See [ask].)

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Actually, the `difflib` module handles such things :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SequenceMatcher` class from the built-in `difflib` module to compare two arrays. Your nested lists will need to be flattened for this to work, which can be done with nested simple list comprehensions:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

ground_truth = [[0,6,234,45,362],
                [1,1,156,103,336],
                [1,36,111,198,416],
                [1,91,42,338,500]]

prediction = [[0,6,234,39,128],
              [0,3,244,39,128],
              [1,1,156,102,180],
              [1,36,111,162,305]]

lst1 = [a for b in ground_truth for a in b]
lst2 = [a for b in prediction for a in b]

print(SequenceMatcher(None, lst1, lst2).ratio())
```

Output:

```
0.45
```

As you can see, the similarity between the two lists is 45%.